# Firebase Auth not working on Safari

Tags: firebase, safari, firebase-authentication

I have read the [post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/_uRh7jkHfZ0/fwY7cpWyAgAJ) by Kato Richardson. I am using Firebase authentication for my web app which is not working on Safari as local storage is not supported on it.

As local storage is useful in case of offline storage only, is there any possibility to go with other storage to persist Auth tokens between pages and visits?

It is necessary for me to make my web app working on Safari. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It should work in Safari in general but not Safari private mode browsing. In the latter, it defaults to in memory storage which is lost after a page reload (signInWithPopup/Redirect does not work though).